# Effects of decision about Hollowborn Souls in PoE2:Deadfire

Tags: pillars-of-eternity-ii

I wanted to start playing Deadfire, using my save file from PoE1. However, I have got a big problem about final decision concerning Hollowborn souls. My watcher was a cruel Death Godlike mage. I was trying to roleplay him as a power hungry wizard. From game point of view, the best choice would be Galawain. My favorite Diety with most interesting dogma is Rymrgand (And I really love frost/snow) From gaining power, Woedica also seems RPish.

However I wonder if there are real differences in Deadfire run, depending on that decision (Without major spoilers)

Comment: In case that's the only reason you're waiting with starting the game - don't fret about this too much. Deadfire happens in an entirely different place of the world, any change your decision brought is not going to have major consequences where you're going. But a detailed answer will have to wait until more people do more playthroughs to catch any dialogue/NPC changes.